# Squid returns 401 even with right basic authentication

Tags: proxy, squid

my squid proxy returns 401 (authorization required) despite of /usr/local/squid/etc/passwd containing right username/password. Now this proxy has been there before i am not sure why /etc/squid/squid.conf is available too. I believe that is right/default path from where squid configuration is loaded. Issue is why i keep getting 401 even if proxy creds are correctly provided. I am wondering if any rule in squid.conf is overwriting and that is causing 401.

```
auth_param basic program /usr/local/squid/libexec/basic_ncsa_auth /usr/local/squid/etc/passwd
acl password proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow password
http_access deny all
```

Comment: Hi, if you haven't already, then have you looked at the /var/log/squid/cache.log.

Comment: This log has not been written since 2014.  Last few lines of log.

014/06/18 23:20:44 kid1| WARNING: log parameters now start with a module name. Use 'stdio:/usr/local/squid/var/log/access.log'
FATAL: Cannot open '/usr/local/squid/var/log/access.log' because
        the parent directory does not exist.
        Please create the directory.

Squid Cache (Version 3.2.3): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.017 seconds = 0.007 user + 0.010 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 57440 KB

Comment: restored default config and enabled above config to make it work. I didn